# How to fix permissions on a linux webserver

Tags: file-permissions, user-permissions

Short version : i can't upload images using php and i have no idea how to fix the permissions issue

Details :

I've been using a vps for around three years now
I set it up to run Sendy (a little newsletter/emailing script)
It is running debian 7

I created a user 'sendy' and the 'www' directory is inside the user folder
/home/sendy/www

The problem is that recently i wanted to start uploading uploading and i realized that the permissions are messed up.

This is what i get on  error.log

```
[Thu Nov 14 12:43:38 2019] [error] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx] (13)Permission denied: file permissions deny server access: /home/sendy/www/mail/uploads/1573731818.png, referer: http://example.com/mail/create?i=3
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Do you have shell access to the server?  You'll need to login and do an `ls -ld /home/sendy/www/mail/uploads` (could update this question with that output) to confirm that the webserver user has write access to this directory.  Also confirm which webserver.

Comment: sure, i disabled ssh root login but i can switch to root user using su  this is what i get ls -ld mail/uploads drwxrwxrwx 4 sendy sendy 4096 nov.  14 12:43 mail/uploads

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact the user "sandy" has the right permission to write in this own home directory (and subdirectories), the web server has an user of it own (usually www-data, nobody, apache, etc). That is the user that is going to do the writing operation.

So, check which user is running the web server daemon, change the ownership of the destination directory to that user and try again.

Considering the message you're mentioning, you should be able to fix with something like the following:

```
chown www-data /home/sendy/www/mail/uploads/
```

Or
    chow sendy:www-data /home/sendy/www/mail/uploads/
    chomd -R g+w /home/sendy/www/mail/uploads/

Either way, we're allowing `www-data` to write into your directory. The first case assumes your `sendy` user doesn't need any access, the latter allows both `sendy` and `www-data` writing your uploads directory.

Comment: www-data is running apache2, can you please tell me how to do the following tasks you suggested ? i don't have advanced linux/bash knowledge.

Comment: Suggested an edit: you should be able to `chown www-data /home/sendy/www/mail/uploads`, or `chown sendy:www-data /home/sendy/www/mail/uploads && chmod -R g=u /home/sendy/www/mail/uploads`

Comment: i changed ownership of the uploads folder drwxrwxrwx  4 www-data www-data 4,0K nov.  14 14:48 uploads. Files are uploaded there (i can see them through ssh or ftp) but i get 403 forbidden error when trying to access them through the browser.

Comment: Then your webserver is somehow preventing access to that path. 1/: avoid 777 chmods. 2/ is this a Centos, redhat, ubuntu, ...? You may have to configure SELinux or AppArmor allowing webserver acceses to home directories (you may be able to disable those, though ideally we should figure out which one is blocking, if any, to configure it appropriately). 3/ look for htaccess files, although I would assume if such exist, they'ld have been shipped with your application and shouldn't be an issue. still, you can look for htaccess files and make sure none would deny accesses to your uploads directory

Comment: 1/ i used the commands above to change ownership. 2/ It's a Debian 7. 3/ there is no htaccess inside that folder